# Use arguments value in sql statements

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc, arguments

I am using **jsp-jdbc** and I want to use the value of a argument in sql statements.

> For eg: http://localhost:3232/file.jsp?name="as"

In the jsp file containing jsp I want:

```
select * from books where name= (the value of argument 'name' in the url)
```

How will it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to get the request parameter.

```java
String name = request.getParameter("name");
// ...
```

You can use [`PreparedStatement#setXxx()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to set an user-definied variable in a SQL string.

```java
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books WHERE name=?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// ...
```

Note that this job doesn't belong in a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info), but in a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) (with a service/DAO class).

#### See also:

- [Advanced Servlets/JSP tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html)
- [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) - [Prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)